# asynchronous aiohttp requests fails, but synchronous requests succeed

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

With the following code I get `Cannot connect to host ...:443 ssl:True` when I use the asynchronous `aiohttp`. When I use synchronous `requests`, it succeeds.

The `whitehouse.gov` links fail, but the `google.com` succeeds for both async and sync cases.

What is going wrong? This is with python 3.4.2 on FreeBSD8, aiohttp 0.14.4, requests 2.5.3

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import requests

urls = [
    'http://www.whitehouse.gov/cea/', 
    'http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb', 
    'http://www.google.com']


def test_sync():
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        print(r.status_code)


def test_async():
    for url in urls:
        try:
            r = yield from aiohttp.request('get', url)
        except aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError as e:
            print('bad eternal link %s: %s' % (url, e))
        else:
            print(r.status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('async')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_async())
    print('sync')
    test_sync()
```

The output from this is:

```
async
bad eternal link http://www.whitehouse.gov/cea: Cannot connect to host www.whitehouse.gov:443 ssl:True
bad eternal link http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb: Cannot connect to host www.whitehouse.gov:443 ssl:True
200
sync
200
200
200
```

Comment: This doesn't reproduce for me on an Ubuntu machine, for what its worth.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect certificate validation chain is broken on your machine.
On Ubuntu everything is working, as @dano mentioned.

Anyway, you may disable ssl validation by creating custom `Connector` instance:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

urls = [
    'http://www.whitehouse.gov/cea/',
    'http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb',
    'http://www.google.com']


def test_async():
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
    for url in urls:
        try:
            r = yield from aiohttp.request('get', url, connector=connector)
        except aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError as e:
            print('bad eternal link %s: %s' % (url, e))
        else:
            print(r.status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('async')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_async())
```

BTW, `requests` library is shipped with own certificate bundle. Maybe we need to do the same for aiohttp?

**UPD.** See also https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/341

Comment: exactly the problem thanks. If I hadn't cleverly hidden behind the try/except, I would have gotten more information that would have helped: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600). Your solution of turning off validation was the trick.

Comment: @Tim, full info for exception points to error source in exception chain, isnt it?

Comment: yes--without the try/except, all the proper info is shown. I was masking the errors with try/except and only got my exception text + "Can not connect to www.whitehouse.gov:443". If I had made the bare connection, I would have seen the full traceback--starting with ssl.SSLError and ending with aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError. lesson learned (don't mask exceptions when developing code!)

Comment: I commonly receive this same exception when setting `ssl=False` in `TCPConnector`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on an old Linux server with out of date CA root certificates, and loading [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) CA certificate bundle in a `SSLContext` fixed the issue.

```py
import aiohttp
import ssl
import certifi

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('https://some.foo/bar/', ssl=ssl_context) as response:
        print(await response.text())
```

Comment: The only answer that worked for me, and my code was already prepared to have it plugged in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use this answere as it might be equal to disabling certificate checks.**

As pointed out by Le Hibou in the comments, `ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH` is meant for authenticating clients on the server side.

> This value indicates that the context may be used to authenticate Web clients (therefore, it will be used to create server-side sockets).

Looking at the code for `create_default_context()` shows that certificate checks might be disabled or at least optional in this case.

---

I had the same error message (on Windows) and solved it with the following:

```py
import aiohttp
import ssl


client = aiohttp.ClientSession()
client.post(
    'https://some.foo/bar/',
    json={"foo": "bar"},
    ssl=ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH))
```

This is using the `ssl` argument of [request()](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession.request) to set a different SSL context than the default. The default is [ssl.create_default_context()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context).

The problem is that the default value for `ssl.create_default_context()` are:

```py
ssl.create_default_context(purpose=Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile=None, capath=None, cadata=None)
```

The `Purpose.SERVER_AUTH` doesn't seem to work when validating server certificates on the client side. Instead use `Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH` when validating as a client.

Comment: This is confusing... According to [The Python Standard Library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH), `Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH` is for creating server-side sockets.

Comment: Good point, I overlooked that. Looking at the source for `create_default_context()` it seems that certificate checking might be disabled or optional with `ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 3 and sys.version_info[1] >= 8 and sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```