# python 3.5 asyncio and aiohttp Errno 101 Network is unreachable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.

I am trying to use aiohttp to write a simple client.

Here is the code I have. I took it from [here](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). It's the first code sample, with ssl check disabled:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout

async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main(loop):
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=conn) as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://www.google.com')
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

For some sites, this code works. For others, including `http://python.org` or `http://google.com` it does not work. Instead, the code generates this error:

```
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 101] Cannot connect to host google.com:80 ssl:False [Can not connect to google.com:80 [Network is unreachable]]
```

I tried a simple `requests` script, something like this:

```
import requests
rsp = requests.get('http://google.com')
print(rsp.text)
```

This works, I am able to reach google. Both curl and wget also reach google.

Doing some research, I came across a different problem. That problem is similar to my own. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827642/asynchronous-aiohttp-requests-fails-but-synchronous-requests-succeed). I tried the solution offered here, but it still does not work.

This issue does not occur for all sites. I came across both http and https sites that worked and did not work.

Any suggestions on why this happens and how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Notes:

Other things I tried.

1. Adding my own DNS resolver, also using aiohttp.
2. Using the https version of the sites, getting the same error.
3. Going to a slightly different url, for example `https://www.google.com/?#q=python`

Comment: Hello! Did you solve this issue? I'm getting the same error only workaround which work fo me (beside specifiying family=socket.AF_INET which i cant do) - create session for each request, but it is not good solution.

Comment: Hey. Yes, but I forgot how, since it was so long ago. Let me check and I'll get back to you if I find the answer.

Comment: Try to add 'family=socket.AF_INET' to the connector or 'allow_redirects=True' (probably it's not this) to the session.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant do this my app stop working at all with this setting, i think maybe you solve this problem somehow differently, thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I see you wrote that, I did not read the question sufficiently well. Since the family flag limits you to IPv4 IPs, perhaps you can have a switch in your code, where domains that can be accessed using a IPv4 address use the async code while strictly IPv6 use something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue when using AsyncResolver as the resolver for the connection. It used to be the default resolver so it might by your case. The problem was related to domains with ipv6 where the AsyncResolver has problems so the solution was to simply specify the family to ipv4 addresses

```
conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(
        family=socket.AF_INET,
        verify_ssl=False,
    )
```

Comment: Looking back through the code, it might be the answer. Unlike the code in the question, now I have the family flag like yours.

Comment: Thank you so much you really saved me here