# aiohttp.request fails on download with status code 404, but synchronous download succeed

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, wso2, aiohttp

I am having a strange problem with an API request.
The problem is that using `requests` or browser, the url I am using works fine. But using an asynchronous servicer the URL fails and returns a status code 404.

Here is my code:
I have build an asynch downloader function `get`:

```py
""" download functions for asynchronous download """
import asyncio
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Dict, Any

import aiohttp

HTTP_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT = 60 * 10


async def _get(
    url: Union[Path, str],
    timeout: aiohttp.ClientTimeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(),
    **kwargs: Union[aiohttp.BasicAuth, Dict[str, Any]]
) -> bytes:
    """
    Base function downloader with aiohttp and async session

    Args:
        url: remote path to file
        timeout: how long should it max take to download the file
        **kwargs: parameters to pass to the aiohttp get function:
            auth: aiohttp.BasicAuth("", "")
            params: Dict[str, Any]
            headers: Dict[str, Any]

    Returns:
        a bytes object
    """
    kwargs["timeout"] = timeout
    async with aiohttp.request("GET", url, **kwargs) as response:
        return await response.read()


def get(
    url: Union[Path, str],
    timeout: int = HTTP_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT,
    **kwargs: Union[aiohttp.BasicAuth, Dict[str, Any]]
) -> bytes:
    """
    download function handling async download with aiohttp

    Args:
        url: remote path to file
        timeout: how long should it max take to download the file
        **kwargs: parameters to pass to the aiohttp get function:
            auth: aiohttp.BasicAuth("", "")
            params: Dict[str, Any]
            headers: Dict[str, Any]

    """
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        _get(url, aiohttp.ClientTimeout(timeout), **kwargs)
    )
```

```py
remote_file='https://api.eumetsat.int/data/download/collections/EO%3AEUM%3ADAT%3AMSG%3AHRSEVIRI/products/MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20210916121242.731000000Z-NA?access_token=43e1b232-02ed-30db-9d17-363f00a4a1f0'
```

Note: token will expire.

Using `requests` works fine. But using my own `get` function yields to:

```
get(remote_file)
b'<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>No matching resource found for given API Request</am:description></am:fault>'
```

Downloading other stuff with my `get` function works fine, too.

So does anyone know why the server returns a 404 when trying to access asynchronously ?

My previous question was closed because some of you thought it is a similar issue to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827642/asynchronous-aiohttp-requests-fails-but-synchronous-requests-succeed): But the reason for this issue was an 443 ssl certification error. I am still receiving 404 If I apply an additional `Connector` the behaviour is the same.

```
connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
get(remote_file, connector=connector)
```

Using:
python==3.9.7
aiohttp==3.7.4

Comment: Please let me know If the token expired

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the URL encoding. For this `yarl` can be used:

```
import yarl


remote_file = 'https://api.eumetsat.int/data/download/collections/EO%3AEUM%3ADAT%3AMSG%3AHRSEVIRI/products/MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20210916121242.731000000Z-NA?access_token=43e1b232-02ed-30db-9d17-363f00a4a1f0'
remote_file_encoded = yarl.URL(remote_file, encoded=True)
```