# Difference between aiohttp.ClientSession().post and requests.post? I've got different responses from server via two packages

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp, binance

I'm coding the Binance Exchange SPI and when I try to create order through rest API, there is some problem.

with the synchronous requests.post(), I got Response[200]：

```
url = self.rest_add + f"{order_url}?{query_string}&signature={signature}"
rsp = requests.post(url, headers=header)
```

However with the aiohttp, I got Response[400], and the binance response text said that my signature is invalid:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
    async with session.post(url, headers=header) as rest_rsp:
        result = await rest_rsp.json()
```

Is there any difference between these two packages?

Answer from similiar question [asynchronous aiohttp requests fails, but synchronous requests succeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827642/asynchronous-aiohttp-requests-fails-but-synchronous-requests-succeed) doesn't work for me T^T

Comment: you need to do a hash for the signature. SHA256(parameter body) with your secret key as hash key. Did you do the hashing?